# How to find list of objects inside a list of objects using where ? (.Net Core Entity Framework )

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, lambda

I am building a gaming website where Games have collection of Categories

```
public class Game
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CategoryMain> categoryMain { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to find list of Games by choosing 1 category from the list of categories.

```
var games= await db.Games.Include(u => u.applicationUser)
                                        .Include(c => c.categoryMain)
                                        .Where(c => c.categoryMain.Id == x) // <-- My Issue Here
                                        .ToListAsync();
```

Because "categoryMain" is a collection, I cannot access it's properties "Id" to filter games by category.

Previously I had Games have 1 category only, things works fine, but now I want to have the ability for games to have multiple categories, so I really need this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the desired result using the `.Any()` method.

```
var games = await db.Games
                    .Include(x => x.categoryMain)
                    .Where(x => x.categoryMain.Any(y => y == categoryId)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Personally, I always find it's easier to reverse the query if you're doing something like this because I find it improves readability.

Something like this:

```
var games = await db.CategoryMain
                    .Include(x => x.Game)
                    .Where(x => x.Id == categoryId)
                    .Select(x => x.Game)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It worked, thank you for your swift help, I appreciate it a lot !